# Error: 7 PERMISOS_DENEGADOS: Permisos faltantes o insuficientes

Tags: firebase, funciones, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

he revisado todas las publicaciones que se han echo respecto a estos permisos, pero por mas que modifico las reglas, me sigue dando el mismo error, incluso esperando unos 10min asumiendo que se deben de aplicar, no funcionan.

---

Tengo un código en Cloud Functions 2da gen que lee información de firestore con las reglas, y ninguna funciona

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
      //allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 7, 28)
      //allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      //allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Y mi base de datos está

```
-Servicios <--Collection Name
    -Grad <--Documents
        -Price(int): 50
    -Sol
        -Price(int): 45
```

Y la información estoy tratando de obtenerla con NodeJS 20

```
//const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.saveFiles = async (res) => {
    console.log("Obteniendo servicios...") //<--Si imprime esto
    try{
        const writeResult = await db.collection('Servicios').orderBy('Price', 'desc').get();
        const totalServices = [];
        writeResult.forEach(doc => {
            totalServices.push(doc.data())
        });
        res.send(totalServices).status(200);
    }catch (error){
        console.error("Ups!", error) //<--Siempre se dispara este error
        res.send(error).status(403);
    }
};
```

A la función ya le permití accesos publicos al crear(Permitir invocaciones sin autenticar) y en el iam `cloudfunctions.functions.invoke` ya la agregué el `PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` con acceso publico, igual la base de datos, pero nada, sigue dando el mismo error. Ya he revisado documentación, pero no encuentro claramente un CRUD o algo similar con la nueva generacion de firebase, aun cuando supuestamente hay [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?hl=es-419#version-2) de los roles, nada. Lo que indican no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El package.json de la generación dos es diferente, la referencia a la libreria correcta está [aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=es-419#node.js) y luego de exportar las [credenciales](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/grading-b1723/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk), me funcionó la 3ra de "Inicializa en tu propio servidor" con el package.json de la siguiente forma:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

Y logré obtener los datos finalmente con:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
//const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Filter } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

initializeApp({
    credential: cert(serviceAccount)
});

const db = getFirestore()

functions.http('getService', async (req, res) => {
    const writeResult = await db.collection('Servicios').orderBy('Price', 'desc').get();
    res.send(totalServices).status(200);
});
```

Las politicas de firestore se quedaron con las conocidas:

```
// Deny read/write access to all users under any conditions
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2024, 7, 28)//Esta se cambia en producción por usuarios autenticados
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra es :

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

El error indica que no tienes los permisos necesarios.

Puedes ir a `Firestore Database` > `Reglas` y asigna los permisos necesarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En modo de **desarrollo** puedes deshabilitar la seguridad asignando todos los permisos, para que puedes leer o escribir información.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

En modo de **producción** puedes requerir que los permisos se autentifiquen para poder leer o escribir información.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero como comento al incio, ya probé todas las combinaciones de las reglas, incluyendo las que me indicas y otras mas... Esperando incluso hasta 10min entre cada nueva regla guardada y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: @AlfaRojo escribe  el error exactamente como se muestra por favor.

Comment: literalmente el error es el `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions` eso sale en consola cuando ejecuto la función. Solo lo traduje para que no me salga alguien diciendo que lo ponga en el stackoverflow en ingles